# Is there a GWT library to interface with the new AppEngine Channel API

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, channel-api

I want to use the new channel API on the appengine side. My client is written in GWT. 
While I could write the client side in Javascript, I wanted to know if there is already a GWT library that does that?

I found [gwt-channel](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-channel) project but didn't see a whole lot of activity on their project page, so I am not sure if that's the right way to go.

Answer (score 4):

here is the official code project:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-channel

Comment: Source: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/8cdf8e0a2276a9dd/0ef8ef81e86dec45?pli=1

Comment: FYI, It's a bit untested/incomplete at the moment but I plan to focus on bringing it up to speed next week and maybe including a sample app as well.

Comment: @JasonHall any updates on the library? I saw on the comments section here that there are some problem with channels not being properly closed.

Comment: Unfortunately it's basically unsupported at this time. If you (or anyone reading this) is interested in taking over maintenance I'd be happy to transfer ownership.